# How to test for the convergence for this sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to test for convergence for this sequence. I am confused and cannot find any solutions for this.

$$\left\lbrace \left(\frac{2n+7}{2n-3}\right)^{n}\right\rbrace_{n=0}^{\infty}$$

Comment: Looks to me that you have to take a limit here. Consider the function $y=(\frac{2n+7}{2n-3})^n$. Take the $ln$ on both sides and now take the limit on $nln\frac{2n+7}{2n-3}$ with $n$ going to infinity. Have you learned how to take these kind of limits?

Comment: Yes. I have just started the chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2n+7}{2n-3}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{5}{n-3/2}\right)^{n-3/2}\left(1+\frac{5}{n-3/2}\right)^{3/2}.
\end{align}

Edit: Here you will not need to use log (maybe. It depends on your definition of $e^x$).

Comment: Yes, I think I got the gist. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As imranfat commented, considering $$A_n=\left(\frac{2n+7}{2n-3}\right)^n$$, take logarithms $$\log(A_n)=n\log\left(\frac{2n+7}{2n-3}\right)=n\log\left(1+\frac{10}{2n-3}\right)$$ Since $n$ is large, consider $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ and replace $x$ by $\frac{10}{2n-3}$ Continue simplifying using long division to get $$\log(A_n)=\left(\frac{5}{n}-\frac{5}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)=5-\frac{5}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ NOw, Taylor again, using $$A_n=e^{\log(A_n)}=e^5-\frac{5 e^5}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.